# XSLT: XPath 1.0 substring

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, xpath, sharepoint-2013

Using XPath 1.0 in XSLT SharePoint 2013, I have two objectives:

1. To extract 'Library Name' from:

   > `/path/to/library/could/be/any/length/Library Name/file.extension`
2. To extract document id **QYZM2HKWQCSZ-3-3** from the following:

   `http://sharepoint01/sites/temp/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=QYZM2HKWQCSZ-3-3, QYZM2HKWQCSZ-3-3`

How to extract the desired strings?

OAN, for some reason Document Id column return the full blown path to the resource as opposed to Id only.

Any suggestions, how to get Id only (to avoid substring preprocessing)?

Comment: It's not enough to give the input string and the desired output string: one example doesn't constitute a specification of the problem. For example in (1) you might be after the last-but-one component of the path, or the part that follows the "length" part, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not possible in plain XPath 1.0 if you cannot find any further pattern in the path.
2. It seems the pattern `?ID=` is fixed, and also the colon following the ID. If so, you can use `substring-after(substring-before(., ','), '?ID=')`. Replace the context `.` by some XPath expression selecting the string.

Answer (score 2):

For (1), write a recursive template as follows. Pass the input string as a parameter.

(a) if `not(contains(substring-after($input, '/'), '/'))` then return `substring-before($input, '/')`

(b) otherwise, make a recursive call passing `(substring-after($input, '/'))` as the parameter.

(c) add some error-handling logic to make sure you terminate if the input string doesn't contain a `'/'`.